# How to reuse Scala type class based API from typeless REST API

Tags: scala, types, typeclass

Imagine you have an API that is meant to be used programmatically so that caller has type information available and can call say `def write[T : Writer](x: T)`.

But now you would like to reuse these type classes from your REST API that is typeless and we don't have the type information at hand, because REST API works with IDs...

Now, given that all instances of `T` are instantiated upfront, we can associate `TypeTag` to it, so your REST API holds a `Map` of `id -> instance-of-T` and it could get the `TypeTag` from that instance to resolve the proper type class that can write it ...

The question is, how do I resolve the type class implicitly having only the `TypeTags` available?

Comment: This sounds like a "XY problem". What do you really want to achieve? `TypeTag` uses the reflection, it won't give you any compile-time safety. Without compile-time safety, why bother with types?

Answer (score 0):

If you're caching all instances anyways, something like this might work:

```scala
trait Entity {
  val id: Long
}

trait Writer[T] {
  def write(x: T): String
}

var cache = Map[Long, (Any, () => String)]()

def cacheObj[T <: Entity](x: T)(implicit writer: Writer[T]): Unit = {
  cache = cache + (x.id -> (x, () => writer.write(x)))
}

def serveObj(id: Long): String = {
  val (x, write) = cache(id)
  write()
}
```

Comment: Hey, I cannot do that. The Writer is actually something that does a lot of different things, it's not anything like serializer. There is only 10 entities by default and then there are entities supplied by users that are obliged to also supply the Writer typeclass evidence. Imagine the Typeclass is rather something like ViewIntrospector which is introspecting Views like s3, ElasticSearch and many more

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of what you want to do with your entity and writer in the REST API?